# Left Shift key increase volume, pipe key works as shift

Tags: 12.10, keyboard-layout

Using a Steelseries Shift keyboard, my left shift key acts as a hotkey to increase volume. My pipe key now functions as left shift, meaning I have no pipe or forward slash character.

xev shows: http://pastebin.com/AFGhN2VH

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and this is how I fixed it :)

Firstly load up the Keyboard settings GUI and click on the Shortcuts tab, look in Sound and Media and disable the Volume up key. Once done you can now use xev to detect the shift key properly and configure with xmodmap.

As we have the same keyboard assuming the key-codes are the same, this should sort out all of the keys except you wont be able to use the volume up key as it shares the same key-code as the left shift.

```
    xmodmap -e "keycode 146 = space"

    xmodmap -e "keycode 123 = Shift_L"

    xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = backslash bar"

    xmodmap -e "keycode 248 = numbersign asciitilde"
```

If it all works you will probably be best making a startup script for it :)

Hope this helps you out.